# Only one box2d object drawn on canvas

Tags: canvas, box2d

I am trying to use Box2dWeb to draw few ball objects in the canvas, without using debugDraw(). I am using the following code to draw circles:

```
function drawObjects()
{
     node = world.GetBodyList();
     while (node) {
            var currentBody = node;
            node = node.GetNext();
             position = currentBody.GetPosition();
            if (currentBody.GetType() == b2Body.b2_dynamicBody) 
            {
                canvas.width=canvas.width;
                context.arc(position.x*30,position.y*30,shape.GetRadius()*20,0,7);
                context.stroke();
                context.fill();
            }
            }
}
```

when I use debugDraw, I am able to see both the Circle objects I am adding. But when try to use canvas methods, only one of the circle object is being displayed.. Any pointers on where I am going wrong? Also I feel I may be doing something fundamentally wrong in my understanding of the box2d methods I am using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're clearing the canvas every time with this line:

`canvas.width=canvas.width;`

Do that at the top, outside of the while loop.

(Changing the canvas width, even to the same value, will clear the canvas. It's often the fastest way to clear it too, which is why you see it used quite a bit)

Comment: Actually, `clearRect` is faster in most browsers today and also the intended way of doing it. http://jsperf.com/canvas-clearrect-vs-width/5

Comment: @bennedich Ah, thank you for that. It's been a while since I last tested it.